# SVG animation behave differently from codepen to my site

Tags: animation, svg, responsive, gsap, viewbox

I created [this animation on codepen](https://codepen.io/gianpiero-di-lullo/pen/dybJeLe) which works perfectly on there but it's all over the place when moved [onto my site](https://littleinferno.co.uk/aa29/#aboutaa29). I've tried to modify viewBox but no joy.

This is how my svg is structured

```
<div class="orbit_container">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 23.1.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="system" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
viewBox="0 0 398.63 251.06" style="enable-background:new 0 0 398.63 251.06;" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="g2">
    <path id="orbit2" d="M326.49,11.26c26.74,0,44.58,7.05,51.59,20.4c4.55,8.67,4.34,19.56-0.63,32.36c-4.86,12.52-14.03,26.3-27.26,40.96
    c-27.29,30.24-68.68,60.74-116.57,85.88c-58.34,30.64-118.71,48.93-161.48,48.93c-26.74,0-44.58-7.05-51.59-20.4
    c-4.55-8.67-4.34-19.56,0.63-32.36c4.86-12.52,14.03-26.3,27.26-40.96C75.72,115.84,117.12,85.33,165,60.19
    C223.35,29.55,283.72,11.26,326.49,11.26 M326.49,10.26c-41.46,0-101.1,17.09-161.95,49.04C65.32,111.4,0.46,183.29,19.67,219.86
    C27.09,234.01,46,240.8,72.14,240.8c41.46,0,101.1-17.09,161.95-49.04C333.3,139.66,398.17,67.78,378.96,31.2
    C371.53,17.06,352.62,10.26,326.49,10.26L326.49,10.26z"/>
    <circle id="planet2" cx="258.35" cy="20.93" r="6.32"/>
</g>

<g id="g1">
    <path id="orbit1" d="M72.14,11.26c42.77,0,103.14,18.29,161.48,48.93c47.88,25.14,89.28,55.64,116.57,85.88
    c13.22,14.65,22.39,28.44,27.26,40.96c4.97,12.8,5.18,23.69,0.63,32.36c-7.01,13.35-24.85,20.4-51.59,20.4
    c-42.77,0-103.14-18.29-161.48-48.93c-47.88-25.14-89.28-55.64-116.57-85.88C35.21,90.33,26.04,76.55,21.18,64.03
    c-4.97-12.8-5.18-23.69-0.63-32.36C27.56,18.32,45.4,11.26,72.14,11.26L72.14,11.26 M72.14,10.26c-26.13,0-45.05,6.79-52.47,20.94
    C0.46,67.78,65.32,139.66,164.54,191.76c60.85,31.95,120.49,49.04,161.95,49.04c26.13,0,45.05-6.79,52.47-20.94
    c19.21-36.58-45.66-108.46-144.87-160.56C173.23,27.35,113.59,10.26,72.14,10.26L72.14,10.26z"/>

    <circle id="planet1" cx="373.84" cy="177.69" r="6.32"/>
</g>
<circle id="earth" cx="199.31" cy="125.53" r="10.32"/>
```

and this is the CSS

```
.orbit_container{
width:400px;
margin:100px auto;
}
#system{
overflow:visible
}
```

Can anyone advise

Thank you

Comment: Try posting just the code relevant to the demo on a new page in your website. If that works, it's a problem with conflict with other things on your website. Try removing pieces (including CSS) to figure out what the conflict is.

Comment: You should probably update your GSAP versions on your site. You are using *really old* versions.

Comment: Thank you Zach, I've updated the GSAP versions and moved the svg animation to [another page](https://littleinferno.co.uk/aa29/artists/) but nothing happened. Then I've deactivated WP Layerslider plugin and the animation stopped completely. This plugin is conflicting with it but I cannot figure out why the animation stopped when I deactivated it. And I get no error in the console

Comment: This sort of debugging is impossible with us to help with as it's environmental issue. Continue to remove things until it works. Once it works, add things back until it breaks.